# Mono for Android, Parcelable & C# - Documentation is Wrong

Tags: c#, android, mono, parcelable

UPDATE:

IParcelable apparently [cannot currently be implemented in Mono for Android](http://android.xamarin.com/index.php?title=Documentation/Limitations).  In the end I used the .NET serialization in the class, and then parceled/bundled the serialized data in the Android-specific code, which works just fine.  It also keeps the class cross-platform compatible, which is desirable.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I'm trying to implement Parcelable as part of a class in a Mono for Android app, but Xamarin's documentation for Parcelable is copy-pasted from the Android documentation:

http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.OS.IParcelable

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
 private int mData;

 public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
 }

 public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
     out.writeInt(mData);
 }

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
     public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new MyParcelable(in);
     }

     public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
         return new MyParcelable[size];
     }
 };

 private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
     mData = in.readInt();
 }
}
```

Since that documentation is written for Java, it's basically wrong for C#.  I'm just wondering if anyone knows how to convert this code into C#.  I'm particularly having trouble with the CREATOR field.

Also, since I'm trying to write code that I can port to other platforms later, what's the best way to implement Parcelable?  Should I make it part of the class using partial classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I often forget with Anonymous Inner Classes (AIC for me) is that the 'types' in the AIC are not translated Directly into C# - they are interfaces, meaning the standard for C# is to start with an 'I.' Also each AIC must be implemented explicitly in c#.

Does the following help?

```
public class Creator : IParcelableCreator
{


    public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class MyParcelable : IParcelable
{


    public int DescribeContents()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I have to admit looking at it again - I absolutely HATE it when a class makes me implement 'IntPtr Handle' - I believe this is a flaw with mono for Android. Typically I try to avoid this kind of thing at all costs. I would rather recreate objects on the other side of an Activity / Intent than pass objects between them.

Comment: Thanks!  Is all that code there equivalent to the Java code from the documentation?  I can't see where the Creator class is used in the MyParcelable class.  Since I don't know much about Java, I don't know what  "public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR" represents, or where it is reflected in the code you've posted.

Comment: The Creator class (my code) returns Java.Lang.Objects. Unfortunately my dev machine died today so I can't test, but you must either:
1. Convert the instance to a Java.Lang.Object - I don't know the specifics of this.
2. Just see if you can change the type (Java.Lang.Object to your specific type) without affecting anything.

Once you have sorted out the type issue with the Creator class - I don't think it will be hectic - then make a public static instance of Creator inside MyPacelable. The rest of the code should be translation.

I am sorry I am not much help :(

Comment: No, no, that's perfect, thanks.  So an Anonymous Inner Class is similar to an anonymous method, where it's defined at the same place that it's used.  That helps me make sense of the Java code.  Question answered, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  On the Mono For Android [limitations page](http://android.xamarin.com/index.php?title=Documentation/Limitations) it explicitly states that IParcelable cannot be implemented.

Comment: Well, they do say that "This will be improved in a future release." and there have been at least 2 updates since 25 Jul 2011 - when the page was last modified. I have not tried the code myself yet but I would tend to also say no - because of the intptr handles flying everywhere.

Comment: Well, in the end I just used the .NET serialization to XML, then parceled the result in Android.  I'd read that the standard Android serialization wasn't usable, but then I realized that was referring to Java, while .NET works fine.  Also, using the .NET serialization keeps this class cross-platform compatible, so in the end it's a moot point whether I can implement IParcelable.  Anyway, the question asked was "can someone translate the code to Java", which was answered.  It would be nice if that limitation was mentioned in the documentation for IParcelable.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I've been running into the same issue. In the end I got it working using the [ExportField("CREATOR")].

So I ended up with

```
public class MyParcelable : Object, IParcelable
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }

    [ExportField("CREATOR")]
    public static MyParcelableCreator InititalizeCreator()
    {
        return new MyParcelableCreator();
    }

    public MyParcelable(string myString)
    {
        MyString = myString;
    }

    public int DescribeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
    {
        dest.WriteString(MyString);
    }

    public class MyParcelableCreator : Object, IParcelableCreator
    {
        public Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
        {
            return new MyParcelable(source.ReadString());
        }

        public Object[] NewArray(int size)
        {
            return new MyParcelable[size];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

From the resources, [Implementing Interfaces](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/android_callable_wrappers/#Implementing_Interfaces)

You have to extends Java.Lang.Object, it avoids you to handle or dispose.

```
public class GroupMetadata : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelable, IComparable<GroupMetadata> {
        public const int REFRESH = -1;
        public int flPos;
        public int lastChildFlPos;
        public int gPos;
        public long gId;

        private GroupMetadata ()
        {

        }

        public static GroupMetadata Obtain(int flPos, int lastChildFlPos, int gPos, long gId) {
            GroupMetadata gm = new GroupMetadata();
            gm.flPos = flPos;
            gm.lastChildFlPos = lastChildFlPos;
            gm.gPos = gPos;
            gm.gId = gId;
            return gm;
        }

        public int CompareTo(GroupMetadata another) {
            if (another == null) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            return gPos - another.gPos;
        }

        public int DescribeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, ParcelableWriteFlags flags) {
            dest.WriteInt(flPos);
            dest.WriteInt(lastChildFlPos);
            dest.WriteInt(gPos);
            dest.WriteLong(gId);
        }

        public static class Creator : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelableCreator
        {
            public static Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
            {
                GroupMetadata gm = GroupMetadata.Obtain(
                    source.ReadInt(),
                    source.ReadInt(),
                    source.ReadInt(),
                    source.ReadLong());
                return gm;
            }

            public static Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
            {
                return new GroupMetadata[size];
            }
        }
    }
```